# Asus Zenbook UX433FN regular 52-56°C CPU heat

Tags: cpu, temperature, ubuntu-18.04, zenbook, ultrabook

I have recently bought an Asus Zenbook UX433FN with an 8th gen i7 and 8GB RAM. I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

After closing the laptop's lid and opening it again, I briefly get to see a black screen with white writing, where the following message is printed over and over again:

> CPUn: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = xxxxxxx)

After checking the CPU heat with the `sensors` app I see that the temperature is in between 52°C and 56°C. I use this laptop for my AI studies, so I usually run `pymc`, `jupyter notebook` and `tensorflow GPU` and I can see why the temperature would get so high when running those. But this temperature also seems to pop up when I access external `jupyter notebooks`.

Is this a normal situation for a Zenbook or should I get worried?

Comment: You shouldn't get worried. Strong notebooks are notorious for heating up, but modern CPUs will either slow down or shut-down when too hot. They will not burn up. You can improve the cooling if you wish to avoid the message or the slow-down. Is this the answer you are looking for?

Comment: Ubuntu may not doing suspend on lid-down. Go to System->Preferences->Power Management, and on both the On AC Power and On Battery Power, check if the lid shut behavior is to suspend. See also [this link](http://tipsonubuntu.com/2018/04/28/change-lid-close-action-ubuntu-18-04-lts/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially, I was having the same issue. The Potential reason for me was that, after closing the lid, the CPU was not at sleep. Most of the time, it remained turned on and rigorously heating up my machine.

What I did to solve this issue:

1. Checked Bios and Turned off Computrace. => This significantly improved the situation.
2. Used Hibernation, instead of sleep
3. Later I Switched to Windows 10 & this never occurred again

On a general note, Yes Overheating can shorten the processor's life and damage the components. But, rest assured that, the manufacturers have already that in mind and so the processors get throttled down to save itself from getting damaged.

But, There's always something, that we can do to improve the situation.

Try checking your bios, putting your computer to hibernate, or Updating the system.

This should fix the issue.